# Округление до кратного значения

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста написать такой скрипт, я уже все перепробовал.

Пробовал `Math.round`, `toFixed`, они не совсем то что нужно делают.

Есть такие массивы:

```
var arr = [2000, 1537, 5491, 3425, 4112];
var arr2 = [5, 8, 11, 3, 13];
var arr3 = [0.009, 0.01, 0.003, 0.014];
```

нужно из этого сделать такое (во внутри может быть 2 или 3 кратные числа, возможно  4-5):

```
var arr = [1500, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5500];
var arr2 = [0, 5, 10, 15];
var arr3 = [0, 0.005, 0.01, 0.015];
```

*варианты разные, от 0.000001 до 10000000, и какие именно числа будут предугадать невозможно*

Вообщем нужно найти минимально значение, и округлить в меньшую сторону до кратного, и найти максимально значение и округлить в большую сторону до кратного числа.

Пока получилось только получить минимально и максимальное значение:

```js
var arr = [2000, 1537, 5491, 3425, 4112];
var minValue = 0;
var maxValue = 0;
for(var ar in arr){
 if(!minValue) minValue = arr[ar];
 minValue = arr[ar] < minValue ? arr[ar] : minValue;
 maxValue = arr[ar] > maxValue ? arr[ar] : maxValue;
}
console.log(minValue);
console.log(maxValue);
```

PS. В исходном массиве важны только минимальное и максимальное значение, другие значения не имеют значения.

Comment: А есть исходная формулировка задачи? По описанию всё равно не очень понятно, что требуется) И как именно мин-макс числа будут влиять на остальные... и почему в arr2 было 5 элементов, а стало 4... и по какому принципу произошли перестановки в массивах)

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME, в arr2 на выходе только кратное значение между минимальным и максимальным значением, может быть 2-3 значения (например: 5, 10, 15 и тд или 100, 200 и тд если большое число)

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME, изменил вопрос, немного упростил результат вариант массива

Comment: Ну... с манипуляцией с числами и массивами вряд ли возникнет проблема. Возможно стоит вернуть предыдущие числа, если именно они вам были нужны) Проблема в формулировке... "кратно" чему?) И, допустим определили мин: 1537 → 1500, макс: 5491 → 5500. Почему тогда 3425 округляется до 3000 а не 3500 ? Куда пропал один элемент из arr2 - все еще загадка. Можно пошагово словами описать, что происходит с числами.

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Видимо, у Вас русский - неродной язык. Попробуйте объяснить на английском.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME, из исходного массива нужны только 2 числа, это минимальное и максимальное значение. На основе этих двух чисел создается новый массив, но только уже с кратными значениями

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Посмотрите ответ. Становится понятно, куда делось пятое число из `arr2`. `8` и `11` отобразились на `10`.

Answer (score 2):

А-а-а, я догадался. Кто же так объясняет!

Вам нужен алгоритм расчета меток шкалы для диапазона значений.

Искать можно по "nice label algorithm".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506881/nice-label-algorithm-for-charts-with-minimum-ticks

Comment: Спасибо, просмотрел там все, но только чуть не то все. Сейчас переформулирую задачу. Допустим есть два числа 10 и 50, 3 кратные чисоа между ними это 20, 30, 40. Еще пример 400 и 800, соответственно 3 кратные это 500, 600, 700. Также и с десятичными числами. Тоесть нужен автоматический поиск кратных чисел между двумя числами.